# What is the license for the iOS Google Mobile Vision Library?

Tags: ios, google-ios-vision

I'm trying to find out what is the license/terms for the iOS version of the library : https://developers.google.com/vision.

Their Cocoapod page mentions both "Custom" in the upper right corner and Apache further down the page : https://cocoapods.org/?q=GoogleMobileVision

I'd like to have the link to the real licensing terms on their website but I can't find it. Looking at the header files themselves, their is not a single copyright claim either.

And finally, if the library is open sourced, where can I find the source code?

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34202190/google-mobile-vision-api-license-for-comercial-app

Comment: This applies to the Android SDK and the license is presented when downloading the Google Play SDK.  In the case of the iOS license, I neither found the full source code nor found the license anywhere on the Mobile Vision page.

Comment: It is basically what is written on the page you linked: The ASF licenses this file to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License")

Comment: If you are talking about the cocoapod page, yes, it mentions the ASF, but it also mentions a "Custom" license in the top right corner of the page. Further more, if the code is open sourced, I would expect to be able to find it somewhere, which I haven't.

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is. The packade in the CocaPods link is licensed under **Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License")** , it is mainated and documented by Google Inc. and that license has been put there by Google Inc. The "Custom" button is only there to link to their website. You can clearly go into the GitHub project mainated by Google Inc. and read the license there in the documentation and in the project: https://github.com/googlesamples/ios-vision/blob/master/LICENSE

Comment: You can check my answer to my own question.  I opened a ticket on Github and they answered.  TLDR; the actual library is not OSS, only the Sample app is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I opened an [issue](https://github.com/googlesamples/ios-vision/issues/2) under the Sample project on Github to inquire about the actual FaceDetection library license and they answered. The actual library is NOT open source and is licensed under those terms : https://developers.google.com/terms/

Comment: I will upvote, reading your question again I see I confused the library with the actual pod you linked.

Answer (score 0):

See [this link](https://cloud.google.com/vision/pricing) about Google **Cloud** Vision API prices, I don't know if this pricing formula is also for Google **Mobile** Vision API.